# Dictionary Wildcard Search

Tags: c#, regex, search, dictionary

I'm trying to create a string search with wildcards and the Dictionary class

```
Dictionary<string, Node> Nodes = new Dictionary<string, Node>();

public bool ResponceSearch(string search) {
     if (Nodes.ContainsKey(search)) {
         label1.Text = Nodes[search].GetResult();
         return true;
     }
}
```

Search strings such as

```
What is that
```

And the Dictionary contains Keys such as

```
Who is *
What is *
```

So the search finds the "what is *" based on the "what is that" search string.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: You're not going to make this work with a dictionary.

Comment: No not with a Dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can change your dictionary keys to be proper [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx), like:

```
@"Who is \w+"
@"What is \w+"
```

Then this problem becomes a lot simpler:

```
public bool ResponceSearch(string search) {
     var node = 
         (from p in Nodes
          where Regex.Matches(p.Key, search)
          select p.Value)
         .FirstOrDefault();
     if (node != null) {
         label1.Text = node.GetResult();
         return true;
     }
}
```

You could even write extension methods for this. For example:

```
public static bool ContainsKeyPattern<T>(this Dictionary<string, T> nodes, string search) 
{
     return nodes.Keys.Any(k => Regex.Matches(k, search));
}

public static T GetItemByKeyPattern<T>(this Dictionary<string, T> dict, string search) 
{
     return
         (from p in dict
          where Regex.Matches(p.Key, search)
          select p.Value)
         .First();
}
```

Comment: If you iterate all Keys then what is the use of Dictionary? Just to hold Key/Value pairs?

Comment: @I4V Well you wouldn't iterate all keys, just until you find one that matches. But yeah, there's no reason this *has* to be a dictionary.

Comment: @p.s.w.g "Well you wouldn't iterate all the keys" - it's expected linear runtime. Might as well use a `List<KeyValuePair<K,V>>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try following. Looks much simpler. The other method that you can use is `string.EndsWith()`:

```
return Nodes.Any(item => item.Key.StartsWith("Who is"));
return Nodes.Any(item => item.Key.StartsWith("What is"));
```

-or-

```
KeyValuePair<string, object> viewDto = ctx.ActionParameters.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Key.ToLower().EndsWith("Who is"));
KeyValuePair<string, object> viewDto = ctx.ActionParameters.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Key.ToLower().EndsWith("What is"));
```